# Writing macro for activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to write a new macro for my ActiveRecord model (User). Macro will be defined in my own gem which called Kart.

Below is my implementation for my gem Kart and User

## kart.rb

```
require "kart/version"

module Kart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def goodbye
      p "Gooooood"
    end
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Kart
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  goodbye # this is my macro, simply print "Goodbye"
end
```

For my understanding, when I run "rails c", "Gooooood" will be printed in the console but error message "`method_missing': undefined local variable or method`goodbye' for User" always shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main problems that I finally figure out:

- I need Railtie to integrate this gem with my rails app. You can find guidance in here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html
- I forgot to rebuild and run bundle update after fixing code in my gem (beginner error but stuck for almost one day)